# How to activate python venv in a non-bash shell?

Tags: shell, python, docker, virtualenv

I see most tutorials/online sources advice using either `source` or `.` (a bash built-in) to activate a python venv. For example, [this page](https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/virtual-python-shell/) suggests to do the following in Linux:

```
cd ~/<proj_name>

. bin/activate
```

(whereas in Windows, it's just `cd\<proj_name>` and
`activate`)

But I need to activate a venv inside a docker/Dockerfile, and bash may not be available (e.g. with podman OCI images). As underlying [distros such as Debian-based](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=35758911) ones adopt [PEP 668](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/), pip commands without the venv in old Dockerfiles [cause an error that "This environment is externally managed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608323). The suggested way now seems to be use venv.

Considering the fact that `source` is specific to certain shells, my questions are:

*Is it always necessary to use `source` to `activate` a venv in Linux?*

*If so, why and what's the proper way to activate venv in a general non-bash shell?*

*In particular, what's the proper way to use venv on pip commands in generic Dockerfiles?*

Comment: Any POSIX compliant shell should understand `.` - the `source` bash shell builtin is just a non-portable synonym

Comment: Also, there's not much sense to making a virtual env in a Docker container. The container itself is a virtual env of sorts.

Answer (score 2):

`bin/activate` is to be sourced (with `.`, though some shells also support the csh `source` as an alias) by any Bourne-like shell (the `sh` or any system since the late  70s and all of ash, dash, busybox sh (ash or mush), ksh, pdksh, mksh, oksh, bosh, yash, zsh...), it is not in any way `bash`-specific.

There's also a `bin/activate.csh` for `csh` or `tcsh` shells, and a  `bin/activate.fish` for the `fish` shell.

If you use any other shell you're on your own, but that shouldn't be too difficult to adapt as it's just a matter of defining or updating the `VIRTUAL_ENV`, `PYTHONHOME` and `PATH` environment variables.

Or you could always re-execute your shell from within a `sh` instead where the `bin/activate` has been sourced. For instance, from the `rc` shell or derivative which don't seem to be supported by python-venv:

```
exec sh -c '. /path/to/bin/activate && exec rc'
```

Would re-exec `rc` with the environment updated by `sh`.

In any case, your container will likely have a `/bin/sh` that is Bourne-like whether that's busybox, mksh or bash.

And to run some command in that container that uses that virtual env, similarly to the above, you'd run:

```
sh -c '. /path/to/venv/bin/active && exec "$0" "$@"' python3 /path/to/whatever.py
```

That's assuming you need to have different virtual envs in a single container for some reason. Most likely you'd be able to use different containers with different sets or python modules or versions of python instead, bearing in mind that containers are some form of virtualisation already.